# How to stop tomcat deleting existing WAR contents when a new version of WAR is to be deployed

Tags: tomcat7, tomcat8

How to stop tomcat from deleting existing WAR contents when a new version of WAR is to be deployed in hot deployment?

Comment: Why don't you try renaming if existing, and then deploy new WAR?

Comment: How should that work? You would then have a mix of old classes and JSPs and new ones. Hardly a recipe for a stable system.

Comment: there are some files like configuration which are customized by customer hence are not required to be overwritten whenever there is a new version of WAR deployed which does not have these configuration files. Hence I thought whether tomcat provides any way to stop deleting the existing set so that the new contents just get overwritten. This would save manual intervention.